Vertical text seems to have an invisible bottom and create a new block
I am playing around with vertical text in my react project
I have this column
    <Col xs={4}>
        <h1 className='japanese-text p-5'><span>ア</span>イ アム コーディング イン リアクト</h1>
    </Col>

which uses the following style
.japanese-text {
  color: antiquewhite;
  font-family: 'Yuji Syuku', serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 1;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #181818, #eee, #181818) 1 100%;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright; 
}

.japanese-text span {
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  background: #981818;
  border: 2px solid #981818;
}

As you can see, compared to the normal text in the column next to it, the vertical text for some reason cuts off and creates a new vertical block when it reaches a certain character count. The only way to prevent it from doing so is to make the font size smaller.

But here is another strange detail.
If I open and close devtools in Chrome, the text becomes correctly aligned

I would appreciate if someone knew what is causing this behaviour.

Do you think you could reproduce it in a stack snippet?  Nothing about the h1 element or the .japanese-text is causing the issue.  The reason must be something about the outer elements.  Please refer to:  I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?

This looks like it's just the text wrapping. Increase the height of the container.
